# Xpath get text within link text

Tags: regex, xpath

i want to get the plain text of this html line :

```
<p>hi i am a developer in <a href="example.com">example</a></p>
```

the plain text should be this :

> hi i am a developer in example

i used this XPath query but it's not work :

```
'//p'
```

anyone can help me to retrieve the text of 'p' with 'a' ?

thanks.

Comment: did you try `'//p/text()'` ?

Comment: yes, but its skipped the text of 'a' tag, just returns the 'p' text. :(

Comment: perhaps this: `//p/descendant-or-self::text()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this xpath query:

```
//p/descendant-or-self::text()
```

Comment: Not sure how this'd help. `$xpath->query("//p/descendant-or-self::text()")->item(0)->nodeValue;` [returns](https://eval.in/95110) only `string(23) "hi i am a developer in "`.

Comment: @AmalMurali: It is because this query return two items: `example` is in the `item(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) for this:

```
echo strip_tags('<p>hi i am a developer in <a href="example.com">example</a></p>');
```

If you want to accomplish this using Xpath, then the following should work:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$node = $xpath->query('//p')->item(0)->textContent;
echo $node;
```

Both output:

```
hi i am a developer in example
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/95107)

Comment: thanks, but i can't use this function in my script because i used xpath in php & can't change the structure of that.

Comment: thanks, your demo work perfectly but i don't know why it's not working in my script!!! i used foreach statement for reaching items instead of item(0) and your suggested code is not work.

Comment: @M2sh: Can you show me how you loop through the items? In my example, I assumed there's only one `<p>` tag and hence directly accessed the index using `->item(0)`. If there are more tags, you can use something like this: https://eval.in/95116

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadXML('<p>hi i am a developer in <a href="example.com">example</a></p>'); 
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); 
$nodelist = $xpath->query("//p");
for($i=0; $i < $nodelist->length; $i++) {
    $node = $nodelist->item($i);
    echo $node->nodeValue . "\n";
}
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
hi i am a developer in example
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the text by using the below `XPath` notation,

```
xpath = "//text()"
```